# Create new hash from original based on specific criteria

Tags: ruby

The code is as follows

```
fruits = { "mango": 5, "orange": 8, "apple": 2}
```

The selected ones are as follows

```
selected = ["apple", "orange"]
```

Now i need to get a hash with the selected ones. Currently, it is implemented as follows

```
h = {}
selected.each do |fruit|
  h[fruit] = fruits[fruit.to_sym]
end
```

This will yield

```
#h = {"apple"=>2, "orange"=>8}
```

Is there any one liner to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fruits = { mango: 5, orange: 8, apple: 2 }
```

```
selected = ["apple", "orange"]
```

```
fruits.slice(*selected.map(&:to_sym))
  #=> {:apple=>2, :orange=>8}
```

See [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) method of the hash

```
[17] pry(main)> fruits = { "mango": 5, "orange": 8, "apple": 2}
=> {:mango=>5, :orange=>8, :apple=>2}
[18] pry(main)> selected = ["apple", "orange"]
=> ["apple", "orange"]
[19] pry(main)> fruits.select {|key, value| selected.include? key.to_s}
=> {:orange=>8, :apple=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one liner of your solution using [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
selected.each_with_object({}) { |fruit, h| h[fruit.to_sym] = fruits[fruit.to_sym] }
```

Notice that I added `.to_sym` also to the first member of the assignment, that's to keep consistency with the fact that keys are symbols:

```
fruits.keys.first.class #=> symbol
```

But it's on you.